# Text from UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have a UITextField with this NSNotification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) name:@"UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" object:_searchTextField];

- (void)textFieldDidChange :(NSNotification *)notif 
    {
     //
    }
```

The NSLog is when I type in `r`

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x193c20 {name = UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification; object = <UITextField: 0x15a980; frame = (20 20; 280 31); text = 'r'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x15aad0>>}
```

How do I get the text `r` out of the notif object?

Comment: You should use the constant UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification (declared in UITextField.h) instead of passing your own NSString as the "name" argument

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The notification's `object` property stores the text field whose text changed, so `notif.object.text` would contain the text "r".

Comment: Its giving an error - Property 'text' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: Do `[(UITextField*)notif.object text]` instead

Comment: Ah yep, so I had to:     UITextField* txt = (UITextField*)notif.object; NSlog(@"%@",txt.text);